# simple function to count plus 1 and negative 1

Tags: r

I am trying to develop a really simple function in r, the idea is that;

Say I have the following sequence `"UUDDDDUDU"` where `"U" = 1` and `"D" = -1`. I want to count the following: `+1, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, -1, +1`. Where I get the final number as -1.

```
funky <- function(n, s){
  current_level = 0
  U = 1
  D = -1
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(s[i] == "U"){current_level +1}
    if(s[i] == "D"){current_level -1}
  }
}

funky(9, UUDDDDUDU)
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `stringr::str_count`

```
s <- "UUDDDDUDU"
library(stringr)

str_count(s, 'U') - str_count(s, 'D')

# [1] -1
```

or more generally

```
library(purrr)

weights <- c(U = 1L, D = -1L)

sum(imap_int(weights, ~str_count(s, .y)*.x))

# [1] -1
```

Base R solution (using weights and s as defined above)

```
sum(weights[strsplit(s, '')[[1]]])
# [1] -1
```

Comment: Thanks! that looks like a simple solution. I would like to complete this in base R however. I will take a look at the `str_count` functions to see what they are using!

Comment: Added a base R solution

Comment: in base R, look at the functions `strsplit` and `regexpr` (and its close friends `grep` and `regexec`)

Answer (score 4):

These methods are in base R and should work with vectors

```
x = "UUDDDDUDU"
```

1

```
with(data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(x, ""), table))), U - D)
#[1] -1
```

2

```
foo = function(p, s) {
   sapply(gregexpr(p, s), function(x) sum(x > 0))
}
foo("U", x) + (-1 * foo("D", x))
#[1] -1
```

3

```
2 * nchar(gsub("D", "", x)) - nchar(x)
#[1] -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun (and vectorised)...

```
s <- c("UUDDDDUDU", "UUDUU", "DDDDDUD")

sapply(parse(text=as.expression(gsub("(.)","\\11",chartr("UD","+-",s)))),eval)

[1] -1  3 -5
```

This translates as...

- replace `U` with `+`, and `D` with `-` (`chartr`)
- replace every character with that character followed by `1` (`gsub`)
- and evaluate these character strings (`"+1+1-1-1-1"` etc) as expressions

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method making use of `reticulate`

```
library(reticulate)
s <- "UUDDDDUDU"
repl_python()
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum([a* b for a, b in zip(Counter(list(r.s)).values(), [1, -1])])
#-1
```